# Table row width by image

Tags: html

need some help with HTML. Have table and where is image is empty place, I dont want that it will be empty.

it Looks like this

[image: two muppets]

and Code:

```
echo "<table  border=2  >";
        echo "<tr><td>Telefono pavadinimas</td><td>Nuotrauka <td>Kaina</td><td>Parduotuve</td><td>Nuoroda</td></tr>";
        for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
        {
        $row=mysql_fetch_row($fetch);
        echo "<tr>";
        echo"<td>$row[1]</td>";
        echo "<td><img src=\"{$row[5]}\"  width=60%  height=60% /></td>";
        echo"<td>$row[2] LT</td>";
        echo"<td>$row[3]</td>";
        echo "<td><a href=\"{$row[4]}\"><img src=\"".base_url()."images/parduotuve.png\" /></a></td>";
        echo"</tr>";
        }
        echo"</table>";
        }
```

Tried

```
echo "<td width=height60% width=60%><img src=\"{$row[5]}\"  width=60%  height=60% /></td>";
```

Also

```
echo"<td width=80><img src=\"{$row[5]}\"  width=60%  height=60% /></td>";
```

but in this use changed and my photo size and column size

So how to detele empty place where is photo?

Comment: don't give specific width. it should take the width of image

Comment: you mean that I must delete width=60% ?

Comment: there is always going to be space if you are setting your image to be 60% of it's width and height, try `<td width="100"><img src=\"{$row[5]}\"  width="100" /></td>`

Comment: Simple and usefull, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the "td" width just "1%". So that it will take only the image size.